# Python Selenium click on a link in the same tr different td

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Hi I would like to click on the Edit Filter button, which appears to be in the same tr for the Fiscal Yr item but in a different td.

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body//tr[@class='FilterEditCell']/td[2]/a[1]").click()
```

Could someone please guide me?

Thanks.

Comment: please don't link images for code - please copy/paste your code as a code block inside of your question.  thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with your current XPath? Did you get any exception?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below XPath:

```
//td[contains(., "Fiscal Yr")]/following-sibling::td/a[img[@title="Edit Filter"]]
```

You might need to use ExplicitWait for dynamic nodes:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//td[contains(., "Fiscal Yr")]/following-sibling::td/a[img[@title="Edit Filter"]]'))).click()
```

Comment: This is the error I received.    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(., 'Fiscal Yr')]/following-sibling::td[img[@title='Edit Filter']]/a").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: That's because you should use `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` instead of `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()`

Comment: After changing this is the error I got.
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(., 'Fiscal Yr')]/following-sibling::td[img[@title='Edit Filter']]/a"}

Comment: 'Timed out waiting for page to load' Tried with added time 30 and 60.

Comment: try with `//td[contains(., "Fiscal Yr")]/following-sibling::td/a[img[@title="Edit Filter"]]`. Note that you shouldn't provide source code as image, but paste it as simple text to avoid such issues...

Comment: Hi I think that XPATH appears to work after I hover the mouse over that row for the button/link to appear. On the webpage itself, I have to hover the mouse over the same tr second td for the 'Edit Filter' button/link to appear.

I can't paste the long code but the class, span after hover have name with 'HighLight' appended. And I can see the td style is now visible <td nowrap="" id="floatcell_hightlightrow0_hightlighttable0" style="visibility: visible;">

Comment: Oh, in this case you may try to implement [`ActionChains`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

Comment: How would I do that? Thank you for your patience and help so far.

Comment: Something like `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(tr_to_hover).perform()`

Comment: I got it to work using td id
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@id="cell1_hightlightrow0_hightlighttable0"]')
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[contains(., "Fiscal Yr")]/following-sibling::td/a[img[@title="Edit Filter"]]')
    hoverover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element1).move_to_element(element2).click().perform()

However, Fiscal Yr may not always be in id="cell1_hightlightrow0_hightlighttable0". How do I use the XPATH to search for Fiscal Yr in the row before hover, then click?

Comment: `element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//tr[./td[contains(., "Fiscal Yr")]])`